# Where and how do I load components from React in Electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a standard index.js and index.html.
I created the app with `npx create-react-app`

And I just want to know where and how I can load react components. I sadly found nothing on the web. I'm kinda new to React and Electron so probably I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: You can set your entry point in package.json `"main": "public/electron.js"`

Comment: Yeah but where can I include an component!